# Use private GemStash repository to install LogStash plugins

Tags: logstash

I'm currently trying to install private LogStash plugins hosted on a private GemStash registry.

In our architecture, the GemStash registry is a mirror of RubyGems as well as a private Gem hosting server which works well if I directly use the gem or bundler binary in Ruby projects.

The GemStash mirror is available at http://my-domain and the private registry is available at http://my-domain/private.

For installing a private LogStash plugins, we need to reconfigure the LogStash Gemfile according to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/private-rubygem.html

When configuring LogStash only with my private registry or only with my public registry or even with both sources, LogStash is not able to resolve my plugins.

Basically, to make it working I should be able to generate the following Gemfile with the `logstash-plugin` install/update command:

```
source "http://my-domain"

# Default LogStash plugins
# ...

source "http://my-domain/private" do
    gem "my-logstash-plugin"
end
```

But as soon as I run any of the `logstash-plugin` commands, the Gemfile is rewritten.

Any idea how to configure LogStash to make it working with GemStash private registry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, replacing the Gemfile source with my two custom domains works well.

The issue was GemStash was load balanced in the AWS cloud and the `private` directory used to store the private Gems was not shared between the GemStash instances...